# refresh client webpage when data changes on server (php or javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, refresh, onchange

I want to present data (which is on the server) on the client (mobilphone). Data is changed rarely (once a day) or frequently (more times in a hour). I dont want to client always asks server because battery of mobil would drain fast. But I want to see the changed data as soon as possible on the phone. Is there any way to do this?
I could use php on the server or php/js on the client. The data is a file and its modified time can be read by server.

Comment: The Client doesn't know when the Server data changes... so, `setInterval(function(){ /* ajax here*/ }, 250);`

Comment: @PHPglue as toncsi said, "I dont want to client always asks server". I agree even web-socket and web push in a way ping server every second but it is better than making a HTTP request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see you have two option that doesn't require the client to keep checking your server (not as much).

- [Web push](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/)
- [Web socket](https://medium.com/@dominik.t/what-are-web-sockets-what-about-rest-apis-b9c15fd72aac)

I suggest use web-socket, which is more practical and with better cross-browser support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer. I have to read more about this, but you have given me the magic word (websocket)  :)